# Can I mount my hangboard on a wooden ceiling beam?

Tags: mounting, hanging, beam, mount

[image]

[image]
[image]

My main worry is that I am 180 lbs and this would have to support my weight

Comment: Are you sure they are real, solid beams and not for show??

Comment: Are there 6 or 8 mounting holes? Is the board shown upside down with the grips hanging below the beam? What is the beam supporting? Is it to be mounted in the middle third of the beam’s span?

Comment: @JACK I am not sure if they are real. Is there an easy way to find that out?

Comment: @LeeSam 8 mounting holes.  That orientation of the hangboard is correct. The middle part is sloper.  I am not sure what the beam is supporting. I heard the most secure place to hang would be on the middle third of the height and not in the middle or the end of the beam's span, so yes, I can hang where it will cause least damage

Comment: What is the beam supporting? What is above the beam?

Comment: @LeeSam It's a single floor apartment with a flat roof so I am guessing that roof. Sorry, not sure if that answers your question

Comment: Try drilling a  small hole into it or tapping with a hammer to see if it's solid. Do the beams go through the walls or end there?  That's a big beam to be real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structural engineer here.

The beam is almost surely not stressed to it's limit. I'm not sure where you are at, that is, if you are in a snow area, but roofs are designed for loads that don't happen all the time such as snow, water, construction, etc.

Also, wood as a material has the ability to resist higher short term loads.

For a beam that size, I would have no problem with what you propose. Because, if that beam  needs to be that size due to loads then the additional 180 lb live load is relatively small. My main concern, as stated in another answer, is HOW you attach it.

Generally you'll be fine with a few screws say of the typical size #8 (length not important) anywhere. If you need larger, stay away from the lower 1/3 of the beam where it is in tension.

Comment: I live in California, so no snow here. I have a bunch of #10s and only a couple of #8s. Do you think #10s will be okay too as long as I mount it in the middle of the thirds?

Comment: Yes, that will work fine. I suggest pre-drilling for the screws with a 1/8" bit (the size of the screw shank). Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues:

1. The existing beam appears to be a solid beam. (You can see several gouges out of the bottom edge.)
2. The beam appears to be stressed to its maximum limits. (You can see gaps between the ceiling boards in the second picture, which indicates the beam and ceiling is bending excessively. This may be seasonal...like when there’s a heavy snow load, or there may be equipment installed on the roof from time to time...like for painting higher walls, roofing, etc.

Nevertheless, the beam seems large enough to add an occasional 180 lbs. hanging from it.

3. I’d install “thru-bolts” instead of “lag bolts” because we don’t know the composition of the beam. I’d also use as large of bolt as can possibly it through the holes in the hangboard.
4. The top of the beam is in compression and the bottom is in tension. The area in the exact middle is called the neutral axis and has no stress. Therefore, I’d install the board as close to the middle (top to bottom) of the beam as possible. I’d also try to determine if the beam extends up into the ceiling cavity to help determine the neutral axis (center of beam top to bottom).

Beams bend mostly in the middle one-third of their span. Therefore I’d try to install it close to a wall...or at least not in the middle third of the span.

Comment: Do you think the spacing showing between several roof boards could simply be caused by either poor initial installation or shrinkage as the lumber dried?

Comment: @MichaelKaras It looks like the space between boards has moved since installation, because the paint looks “torn” at the joint. That is to say, the board has moved since original installation. I doubt the board has shrunk because it appears at only one end ...not all he way along the board. Also, the material appears to be faux wood because it’s made in “pairs” for appearance.

Comment: For #3, I have only screws. I have neither thru-bolts nor lag bolts. Would normal #10 screws work?

Comment: @THISUSERNEEDSHELP Because we really don’t know the composition of the beam, I suggested thru-bolts. If the beam is “solid”, I’d use the bolts/screws that the manufacturer recommends. Did they send #10 screws with the Hangboard? I Googled “hardboard” but couldn’t find anything about recommendations for installation. I’d use the biggest available that will fit through the hole. Btw, I see the hangboard is fairly thick, so make sure they’re long enough to penetrate the beam as much as possible without coming out the other side.

Comment: @THISUSERNEEDSHELP I see that your fingers can dig in when on the very top of the unit. When your fingers press against the face of the beam while you hang on, it can create a tendency for the unit to “rotate” away from the beam. Make sure the screws are plenty long enough on the top row of holes to resist this rotation...if you can’t install thru-bolts.